# AppLink Configuration for Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, android-deep-link, android-app-links

How can I modify the `assetlinks.json` if I'm using the firebase provided domain for my dynamic links? It's accessible and currently it's returning empty array:

https://setel.page.link/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify it to get a non-empty response. That said, I'm having the same problem. Did you do everything described in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zra2DCd0DnY ?

Answer (score 6):

Firebase Dynamic links requires using a SHA-256 fingerprint instead of a SHA-1 fingerprint. You can add on firebase console.
On Firebase Project Settings select your app and click on "Add fingerprint".

To see the SHA-256 from your keystore you can use this command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

You can see more details about the SHA on [Firecasts - Introdution to Firebase on Android](https://youtu.be/cNPCgJW8c-E?t=183)

So it may take a few minutes to your assetlinks.json to update on https://the_name_you_chose.page.link/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Comment: Are you sure about few minutes? Or better to do remove and add new URL prefix?

Comment: Waiting ~1h worked out for me. Thanks a lot.